# Pygame eroor Rect arguement is invalid

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, rect

In this code, I have written online 153 where I want to draw rectangles but the code says the rectangle arguments are invalid but the argument is valid I don't know why the error is occurring as i can't understand why this problem is happening can anybody help???

```
import pygame
import random
import time


def basic_defaults():
    pygame.init()
    snake_x = 200
    snake_y = 175
    font_for_game_title = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) #Making Screen for the game
    screen.blit(font_for_game_title.render("Snake Game", True, (0, 255, 255)), (300, 10))# Making title appear
    Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    x=2
    counter = 0
    score = 0
    coordins = []
    eaten = 0
    return screen, snake_x, snake_y, Clock, x, counter, score, coordins, eaten


def snake_movements(x):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                x=1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                x=2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x=3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x=4
            else:
                pass
    return x


def food():
    food_x = random.randint(20, 780)
    food_y = random.randint(20, 280)
    return food_x, food_y










def game_loop():
    screen, snake_x, snake_y, clocko, x, counter, score, coordins, eaten = basic_defaults()
    running = True
    while (running):

        #for moving of snake in the game [code starts]

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        x=snake_movements(x)
        if x == 1:
            snake_y -= 20
        elif x == 2:
            snake_y += 20
        elif x == 3:
            snake_x -= 20
        elif x == 4:
            snake_x += 20
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (102, 255, 51), (snake_x, snake_y, 10, 10), 0)

        #for moving of snake in the game [code ends]

        #for food appering and disappearing after certain amount of time[code starts]

        timesec = 35       #in secs
        if (counter)%timesec == 0:
            food_x,food_y=food()
        else:
            pass
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 255), (food_x, food_y, 11, 11), 0)
        counter += 1

        # for food appering and disappearing after certain amount of time[code ends]

        # for detecting snake is eating food or not [code starts]

        if snake_x + 10 >= food_x and snake_x + 10 <=  food_x + 10 and snake_y >= food_y and snake_y <= food_y + 10:
            food_x, food_y = food()
            counter = 1
            score += 1
            eaten = 1
        elif snake_x >= food_x and snake_x <= food_x + 10 and snake_y >= food_y and snake_y <= food_y + 10:
            food_x, food_y = food()
            counter = 1
            score += 1
            eaten = 1
        elif snake_x >= food_x and snake_x <= food_x + 10 and snake_y + 10 >= food_y and snake_y + 10 <= food_y + 10:
            food_x, food_y = food()
            counter = 1
            score += 1
            eaten = 1

        elif snake_x + 10 >= food_x and snake_x + 10 <= food_x + 10 and snake_y + 10 >= food_y and snake_y + 10 <= food_y + 10:
            food_x, food_y = food()
            counter = 1
            score += 1
            eaten = 1

        else:
            eaten = 0
            pass

        # for detecting snake is eating food or not [code ends]

        # to determine boundaries for snake to not go beyond [code starts]

        if snake_x > 790 or snake_x < 0:
            running = False
        if snake_y < 0 or snake_y > 590:
            running = False

        # to determine boundaries for snake to not go beyond [code ends]

        # code to calculate score [code starts]

        font_for_score = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
        screen.blit(font_for_score.render("Score: ", True, (0, 147, 255)), (645, 10))
        screen.blit(font_for_score.render(str(score), True, (0, 147, 255)), (705, 10))

        # code to calculate score [code ends]

        # code to extend tail of snake [code starts]
        if eaten == 1:
            coordins = []
            for i in range(score + 1):
                coordins.append("None")
        if score > 0:
            dolo = score + 1
            dhillo = (counter-1)%dolo
            coordins[dhillo] = [snake_x, snake_y]
            for i in coordins:
                snake_xo = i[0]
                snake_yo = i[1]
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (102, 255, 51), (snake_xo, snake_yo, 10, 10), 0)        

        # code to extend tail of snake [code ends]



        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        clocko.tick(30)
game_loop()
```

[Error code in pcharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSl4E.png)
please help as I need to complete this code of snake game as the code is close to completing so please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Of course the argument is invalid. `coordins.append("None")` adds a string element  `"None"` to for each part of the snake. The 1st element  is change by  `coordins[dhillo] = [snake_x, snake_y]`, but all the other elements are still `"None"`. Finally `snake_xo` contains `"N"` and  `snake_yo` contains `"o"`.

Comment: thanks buddy really appreciatiate your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that when you eat the apple, your score increases and reaches 1.
`coordins` contains `["None, "None"]`.
Then `coordins[0]` is updated to the snake position, but not `coordins[1]`
After this you loop in `coordins`.
You can draw `coordins[0]` without problems, because you replaced it from `"None"` to the coordinates.
However `coordins[1]` is still `"None"`.
`snake_xo` become `"N"` and `snake_yo` become `"o"`, because they are the first characters of `"None"`.
Then you try to draw the rect, but the coordinates are `str`, not int, and it crashes.
In order to fix this you need to fully update `coordins` not only one element.
Hope this helped